# Sqlalchemy on POST check if record already exists and send back the existing record

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I've a few endpoints across which I have the same type of problem. Checking if a record already exists. In this particular instance I'm verifying if a record with the same value for `url` has already been added to the database.

### Endpoint

```
api.add_resource(EventEntries, '/events/<int:event_id>/entries')
```

### Loader

```
class Entry (Resource):
    #RETURNS A SINGLE EVENT
    def get(self, entry_id):
        schema = EntrySchema()
        result = db.session.query(EntryModel).filter(EntryModel.id == entry_id)
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200

    #PUTS A SINGLE EVENT
    def put(self, entry_id):
        event_id = event_id
        title = request.json['title']
        description = request.json['description']
        type = request.json['type']
        domain = request.json['domain']
        language = request.json['language']
        publishdate = request.json['publishdate']
        url = request.json['url']

        entry = EntryModel(event_id=event_id,title=title,description=description,type=type,domain=domain,language=language,publishdate=publishdate,url=url)

        db.session.add(event)
        db.session.commit()

        data = ({'id' :entry.id,
                        'title': entry.title,
                        'description': entry.description,
                        'type': entry.type,
                        'domain': entry.domain,
                        'language': entry.language,
                        'publishdate': entry.publishdate,
                        'url': entry.url})

        response = jsonify(data)
        response.status_code = 200 # or 400 or whatever
        return response
```

### The modification

I modified the above file to include the following lines which check if a record exists and attempted to return the record. This results in an empty array being sent back even when the entry doesn't exist.

```
    # If record already exists
    schema = EntrySchema()
    result = db.session.query(EntryModel).filter(EntryModel.url == request.json['url'])
    print(result)
    print(request.json['url'])

    if  result is not None:
        print("Record Already exists")
        return schema.dump(result, many=True), 200

    else:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

I added this instead of the suggested above.

```
    # If record already exists
    schema = EntrySchema()
    result = db.session.query(EntryModel).filter(EntryModel.url == request.json['url']).first()
    print(result)

    if not result is None:
        print("Record Already exists")
        return schema.dump(result, many=False), 200
```